# Blender 2.81 toolbar selects tools randomly

Tags: interface

In Edit Mode, when I click on SHIFT+SPACE to make Blender 2.81a ToolBar appear, this is what happens

1. it automatically and randomly select one tool
2. the toolBar appears and disappears automatically 
   So I got to do SHIFT+SPACE twice to make the ToolBar appear and stay on the viewport so that I can choose the tool I want. 
   Is it normal? If not, How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> by default brings up the tools menu, this can be temperamental in how long it stays visible. Holding space down usually helps to keep it open.

The menu will normally show up positioned so that the last tool used is under the cursor, if the cursor is near the top or bottom of the window it gets moved so that it can be fully shown in the window. This can be part of what leads to it selecting a new (random?) tool and disappearing quickly.

You may find displaying the toolbar on the left side by pressing <kbd>T</kbd> to be easier.